# How to optimize CPU utilization while running Maven tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, cpu-usage

I have quad-core processor. And when I run 'mvn test' in my project, the CPU is loaded almost on 100%:

```
 PID   USER     PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND   
 20641 user     20   0 3338212 339232   5076 S 397.7  9.1   2:16.19 java
```

And my unit tests because of elapsed timeouts. When I'm using eclipse plugin for JUnit tests run faster and don't load CPU on 100%. My configuration is as following...

```
Maven 3.1.0
JUnit 4.10
Oracle JDK 1.7.0_40
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem? May be I should to do some configurations with maven or use maven-surefire-plugin with specific configurations?

Comment: hard to say without your test. If you test you decryption algorithm, that wouldn't be a surprise. If you test "Hello, World", it would be strange.

Comment: In some of my tests I create new thread, which has to wait (with some timeout) some notification from another thread.

Comment: Can you show the full configuration for maven-surefire-plugin in particular do you use multithreading configuration, forking JVM etc. ?

Comment: I don't use maven-surefire-plugin. I just run tests as:
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -classpath /usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.0/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.2.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.0 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher test

Comment: @DmitryKrivenko did you fix this? If so can you post your answer, I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

You should connect to that VM with a profiler and analyze where CPU time is spent. For quick results, you can use [Java Visual VM profiling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html). For more detailed analysis, use a professional profiler.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), too. There is another tool which could be helpful, it's called [jvmtop](http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/) and for the commandline.

You should also make sure that you don't spawn more threads then cores available, since the swapping will use the CPU a lot. Also be aware of the way your threads are waiting, since such a high CPU load happens when the thread is in a tight loop, e.g. `while(!foo) {}` ... etc

Answer (score 1):

Setting the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable ensures that adequate memory is available to run Maven tasks and lessen CPU utilization.

On Mac OS X you can edit your .bash_profile file and add the following:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

Restart the terminal session or run source .bash_profile to activate the environment variable.
On Linux you can edit your .bashrc file and add the following:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

Restart the terminal session or run source .bashrc to activate the environment variable.
On Windows, set environment variables at user level

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

Your MAVEN_OPTS environment variable is now set. Feel free to increase the specified values if required, for example, if you get "out of memory" errors when running your projects.